# Weblogic 12c versions, servlet failed to preload

Tags: jar, jersey, weblogic12c

Been scratching my head for about a day, I'd really appreciate any help.

- Using Weblogic 12c version 12.**2.1** and Jersey 1.19 everything is OK
- Using Weblogic 12c version 12.**1.3** I'm getting this error:

> Servlet:"ServletAdaptor" **failed to preload** on startup in Web application:  "PapWeb".java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   65281

Edit: I also see this related(?) warning when running the 12.1.3 server:

> The application is using ServletContainerInitializer class
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
>   that is loaded
>   from:file:/D:/servers/wls12130/oracle_common/modules/jersey-servlet-**1.18**.jar.
>   This initializer overrides the one available in the system.

WEB_INF/lib includes those jars:

- jersey-**1.19**
- jersey-core-**1.19**
- jersey-multipart-**1.19**

  My web.xml has:

  ```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>gr.modas.core.bussiness.services</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>gr.modas.core.bussiness.services</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>gr.modas.core.bussiness.services.PapyrosRequestFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below (in weblogic.xml) solved the issue...

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>**true**</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```